# Source Code of Ext JS Examples

Tags: extjs

I saw some examples from a JavaScript library: Ext JS i.e.:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/feed-viewer/feed-viewer.html

I have some knowledge about JQuery developed some applications. How can I get sources of that examples to try them myself and what should I download to run them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are in the extjs package   /ext-4.0.2a/examples/key-feed-viewer.

Download link:

http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/download/ext-js-4.0.2/204

**UPDATE**.

Newest versions of Ext js for download are:

- For Extjs version 4.2.0 you can [download it here](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/download/ext-js-4.2.0/2142)
- Ext js 5 can [download it here](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/#try) ( Ext js 5 has a trial period )